# Django Middleware, single action after login

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, django-middleware

Let's say I created a Middleware which should redirect user after login  to a view with "next" parameter taken from `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. But it should do it only once directly after logging, not with every request to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. At the moment  I check `User.last_login` and compare it with `datetime.datetime.now()`, but it seems not to be a reasonable solution. Any better ideas?

Comment: You can look at the referer. `HTTP_REFERER`

Comment: middleware catches all requests, why do you not use a view?

Comment: @vadimchin I need a middleware, because  I want to  let  not authorised users to take free steps around "logged Area", so i create "visitor user"  in middleware,  and when he attempts to any of  "logged area" views I want to show a view with a notification. I could make a decorator to "logged area" views, but i want it all in a middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. I created signal for user_logged_in action, thats add a variable `redirect_me=True`. Thats that i had still the same request in middleware,  I could check it and make and redirct. Thats a sample code here:
signals.py:
    from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

```
def do_stuff(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    if getattr(request, 'user', None) and not request.user.is_superuser:
        request.do_stuff = True
```

models.py (you also can place it in **init**.py, or other file that is run initially on 'runserver'):

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
user_logged_in.connect(do_stuff)
```

middleware.py:

class PrimordialAdvertMiddleware(object):

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
        if getattr(request, 'do_stuff', None):
            return do_some_other_stuff()
        return response
```

You make a  process_request action as well.
I hope that it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use user_logged_in signal instead of middleware?

Also you can check user object from request for is_anonymous, maybe it can helps

Comment: Aren't signals supposed to run actions in background? how can i redirect user to URL inside of signal? Besides i check user object from request, but i want to redirect ONCE, only direclty after login.